# Yielding self object in method_missing method (ruby)

Tags: ruby

I've encountered a part of code in a Ruby book I can't understand. I've simplified it to make it to point out my question (full code is here: https://paste2.org/keKv8Yea)

```
class C
  def method_missing(m, &block)
     p yield(self)
  end
end

c = C.new
c.groceries do |item|
  item.name {'Apples'}
end
```

The execution of `yield(self)` outputs "Apples" string twice - but why?
I can't catch the sequence of what happens after yielding that self:

1. Instance of C class - c - calls method `groceries` which is absent;
2. Since the method is missing, the execution is taken over by `method_missing`;
3. self in `method missing` is the instance itself - instance of C class;
4. ...

So where is `self` yielded to? To which block? And why do we need to pass the whole instance to a block? I can't get what happens after that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4. `self` is yielded to that block you passed to `groceries`, where it is called `item`

   ```
                do |item|
      item.name {'Apples'}
    end
   ```
5. The block calls `#name`. It's absent, so `method_missing` is involved again.
6. That same instance of `C` is yielded to yet another block. That block simply evaluates to the hardcoded string literal `'Apples'`.
7. `method_missing` for `:name` receives that string, prints it **and** returns it (this is what `p` does)
8. We're now back in `method_missing` for `:groceries` and the block evaluated to a string `'Apples'`, so again we print and return it.
9. Our program is finished.

Comment: @Mirat you need to indicate that this is the "accepted answer" so that Sergio gets full credit for his work